# echo statements with commands

Tags: date

I want to create a echo statement in a Bash script that will say "Today is (current date and time)".

so far I've tried:

```
today=date

echo Today is $today
```

but no luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To embed commands into other ones, either wrap them in ``` `` ``` or in `$()`.

Examples:

```
echo Today is $(date)
echo Today is `date`
```

Answer (score 0):

the right one is:

```
today=$(date)
echo Today is $today
```

In other words, use the `variable=$(commands)` syntax, it will save the result of command into `variable` and so if you want to printout the what was the result? you can use:

```
echo $variable
```

<sub>here is the similar example http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bsd-appleosx-bash-assign-variable-command-output/</sub>